# Visual Studio doesn't open my project RC file any more

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2012, mfc

Something came up, and I had to restart my computer unexpectedly. Visual Studio was open, but minimized.
Now when I open my project, it can compile and run, but I can't edit the resource with Resource View.

When I try to expand the resource in *Resource View*, I get the following sequence of errors:

- {VSInstallationDir}\VC\include\sal.h(2872) - warning RC4005: '__useHeader' : redefinition
- {VSInstallationDir}\VC\include\sal.h(2882) - warning RC4005: '__on_failure' : redefinition
- \MyProjectName.rc(199) - error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT

When I click on OK, I see this error in Resource View tree list: Load Failed.

I searched the net but no one had the same exact problem. Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you open the .rc file in the code editor (rightclick -> View Code)? If so, does the code editor indicate any errors with squiggly red lines?

Comment: Yes, I do. I removed line 199 and resource was opened successfully. But I still get the first two errors. Why is that?

Comment: This could be a bug related to using the platform toolset for Windows XP ([Connect link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789965/resource-editor-warning-rc4005-on-toolset-visual-studio-2012-windows-xp-v110-xp) - with a workaround). Before doing that you could probably try to set the platform toolset back to its default setting (Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General: Platform Toolset). The default setting is *Visual Studio 2012 (v110)*.

Comment: I'm getting this warning while building. The Microsoft Connect link is dead and I still have to support XP. I added _USING_V110_SDK71_=1 to the Preprocessor Definitions in Resources->General property pages and that resolved the build problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed.

First, I clicked on *Edit Code* button and the source appeared. I went to line 199 and found `WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT` and removed it. When I reopened the resource, the last error was gone.
I reopened the whole project and all errors were gone.